# how to create libhidapi.dylib from source?

Tags: c, macos, firemonkey, dylib, hidapi

I have ongoing cross platform project (Win and Mac) where I need to access USB device. I have found HIDAPI library that perfectly fits all my requirements. Since there is no Delphi Firemonkey wrapper for HIDAPI library (at least I don’t know for one) I am writing my own.

HIDAPI project web site http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/ says:
“On Windows, HIDAPI can optionally be built into a DLL. “

This is true because I have successfully compiled source using visual studio and created DLL which works perfectly on Windows. Now, since I am not C programmer and OSX is not my strongest skill I would like to know is it possible and how can I create libhidapi.dylib from given source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing your question... but it looks like right at that link you provided there are instructions you need to compile as a `.so` for Linux/Mac platforms. Then you can use the links from Mac:

- [ld(1)](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ld.1.html) and [dlopen(3)](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dlopen.3.html)
- [Dynamic Library Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/000-Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [Mach-O Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachOTopics/0-Introduction/introduction.html)

To compile as a Mac dynamic library (.dylib).

> Build Instructions
>
> ...
>
> Mac OS X: 
>   Change to the mac/ directory and run make.
>
> To build the Test GUI:
>
> On Linux and Mac, run make from the hidtest/ directory. Make sure to first install fox-toolkit as >described in README.txt

Then the README itself tells you what prerequisites there are to build for mac, and how to generate the final shared object library:

> ```
> Prerequisites:
> ---------------
> ```
>
> Mac:
>
> On Mac, you will need to install Fox-Toolkit if you wish to build
>     the Test GUI. There are two ways to do this, and each has a slight
>     complication. Which method you use depends on your use case.
>
> If you wish to build the Test GUI just for your own testing on your
>     own computer, then the easiest method is to install Fox-Toolkit
>     using ports:        sudo port install fox
>
> If you wish to build the TestGUI app bundle to redistribute to
>     others, you will need to install Fox-toolkit from source.  This is
>     because the version of fox that gets installed using ports uses the
>     ports X11 libraries which are not compatible with the Apple X11
>     libraries.  If you install Fox with ports and then try to distribute
>     your built app bundle, it will simply fail to run on other systems.
>     To install Fox-Toolkit manually, download the source package from
>     http://www.fox-toolkit.org, extract it, and run the following from
>     within the extracted source:        ./configure && make && make install

And how to generate the .so:

> Building HIDAPI into a shared library on Unix Platforms:
>
> On Unix-like systems such as Linux, FreeBSD, Mac, and even Windows,
>   using Mingw or Cygwin, the easiest way to build a standard
>   system-installed shared library is to use the GNU Autotools build
>   system.  If you checked out the source from the git repository, run
>   the following:
>
> ./bootstrap     ./configure     make    make install     <----- as root, or
>   using sudo
>
> If you downloaded a source package (ie: if you did not run git clone),
>   you can skip the ./bootstrap step.
>
> ./configure can take several arguments which control the build. The
>   two most likely to be used are:   --enable-testgui        Enable build of
>   the Test GUI. This requires Fox toolkit to        be installed. 
>   Instructions for installing Fox-Toolkit on        each platform are in the
>   Prerequisites section above.
>
> --prefix=/usr       Specify where you want the output headers and
>   libraries to      be installed. The example above will put the headers in
>         /usr/include and the binaries in /usr/lib. The default is to
>         install into /usr/local which is fine on most systems.

So you should be able to just follow those instructions but modify the `.dylib` extension and add the build flags: `-dynamiclib` and `-fPIC`

Comment: Hello Mike, 
Thank you for your reply. I forgot to mention that I have successfully compiled C file and testgui application by following instructions from readme file that you quoted. What I did not know is how to create dylib which beginning of your post answers 100% correct. Actually this is exactly what I was looking for:
“Then you can use the links from Mac:
    ld(1) and dlopen(3)
    Dynamic Library Programming Topics
    Mach-O Programming Topics
To compile as a Mac dynamic library (.dylib).”
Once again thank you very much for a great reply.